# What is a good way to generate a set of (relatively) short "invitation codes"

Tags: c#, sql-server

During the signup process for my app, users will be asked if they have an invitation code. This is a way to recognize "VIP" users and instantly give them access, rather than sticking them on a waiting list.

I have everything (mostly) figured out, but am clueless as to how to create sets of unique codes, and what the best way to store them is. What is a generally accepted practice for something like this, and how should I store the values in SQL (as a string, or as a binary value, or what?)

Thanks!

---

**Edit 1**

- Any random set of numbers/letters is fine. There doesn't need to be any particular format.
- Each VIP user will have their own code
- There will (probably/hopefully) be a few thousand codes handed out.

Comment: Isn't some random string with only digits and letters enough?

Comment: How many codes are you looking to create?  Will each VIP user have their own?  Do they need to follow a form or any jumble of letters and/or numbers will do?

Comment: Also, will the codes be paired with an user-end identifier, like an e-mail address, or be stand-alone, so they can be passed around between people?

Comment: @Dave.Gugg I just posted an update to my question. Does that help?

Comment: @barthazar I was planning on storing the codes in their own table, then marking them as "used" once the code has been redeemed (at signup).

Comment: It looks like flup's link gives you a good way to do this.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg yes, I believe that is what I am looking for. If I use GUID, should I store the tokens as a string in my DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have information about the user that is presumed to be unique, such as email you can create a hashcode based on that info.

userInfo.email.GetHashCode();

Now that is not horribly pretty. but it works.

Another method that I used is to create a dictionary of inspirational quotes. 
pull one from the dictionary at random, put that into their profile;
My register link that I give them prefills in the quote field and hides it if it comes in via the URL and is a match.
When they submit their data to create their account their email & quote have to match.

What you need to consider is how likely people would try to hack a VIP account. If security is a concern then you need to send an encrypted hash. But if this is not going to be protecting a 'high value' target, then consider the user experience, and advancing your brand. That is why I opted for a quote.

Don't use something that is difficult for the user to enter, if they can't cleanly copy & paste from the invitation.

Comment: I love the quote idea! Thanks a ton for the advice!

Comment: In that case - "If you think you can do a thing, or believe you can, begin it! Boldness, has genius, power and magic in it."

Comment: -1 NB the actual `GetHashCode` should not be abused for this - it is not intended for this purpose, and exposes and/or makes things contingent on implementation details of how hash codes are generated for strings (or whatever `email` is) - the sole thing it's great for deciding buckets in dictionaries.